# ThemeProvider not applying

Tags: material-ui

I just started material UI today. So far, I fail to apply a theme to my react-app, and I cannot see why...I don't have any error message. I checkd the examples on the material UI website, and it seems identical... any idea would be welcome :(

here is my code:
index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import 'fontsource-roboto';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import theme from './theme.js'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter> 
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}> 
          <App />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

theme.js

```
import { red } from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
// A custom theme for this app

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
       type:"dark",
      main: '#115293',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#19857b',
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400,
    },
    background: {
      default: '#115293',
    },
  },
  typography: {
     fontFamily: 'Arial',
  }
});

export default theme;
```

thank you for your time and patience, on what must be a very stupid mistake on my side è_é

Comment: `type:"dark"` should be above `primary:`

Comment: Could you please create codesandbox example?

Comment: @Spatz OK thanks. I changed it, but I did not notice a chance

Comment: @Medi thanks for your time! https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-hoover-dew8q?file=/src/App.js:584-944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add [`CssBaseline`](https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/), some styles won't work without it:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import theme from './theme.js'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter> 
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}> 
          <CssBaseline />
          <App />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thank you Spatz, it worked! I don't understand why it is not mentioned on the "theming" page of material UI :/